# How can I set the value of an AppleScript variable to the result of a shell script's cURL request?

Tags: curl, applescript

Why doesn't the following work?

```
set myIP to (do shell script "/usr/bin/curl icanhazip.com")
log myIP
```

If I run `/usr/bin/curl icanhazip.com` from command line it returns as expected.

How can I set the result to the value of an AppleScript variable?

Comment: Run curl from the command line and get it outputting its results to a file. Then, in your script make the last line 'cat thatfile'

Comment: If your script is a one-liner, add a semi-colon to the end before adding 'cat thatfile'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Script works on my machine (OS X 9.2). Try this for testing purposes:

```
set myIP to (do shell script "/usr/bin/curl icanhazip.com")
display dialog myIP
```

Comment: Interesting. That works.  Why would `log` not work, but `display dialog` work?

Comment: Ugh, never mind. I had the AppleScript Editor on the "Result" tab instead of "Events" tab. Frustrating.

Comment: I have tried this with  set deviceid to (do shell script "system_profiler SPUSBDataType | sed -n -e '/iPad/,/Serial/p' -e '/iPhone/,/Serial/p' | grep \"Serial Number:\" | awk -F \": \" '{print $2}'") but this doesn't work any idea why ??